# How R compares dots with other characters?

Tags: r, string

In R I get the following results:

```
> ".c" > "ab"
[1] TRUE
> ".a" > "ab"
[1] FALSE
```

It doesn't seem like a dictionary order to me. How its order is defined and how can I compare R characters in dictionary order?

Comment: This is rather complicated, but explained well in `help(">")`.

Comment: Mmh... actually both lines return FALSE on my pc...(as expected from lexicographic ordering...)